# Fire a query on Excel Sheet and populating the result in a ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a two columns named "Company" & "Project"

I want to select all Projects for a particular Company & populate the resulting list of Products into a ComboBox.

I think ADODB would be the best way to achieve this.
I don't know how to make Connection, Command Object etc. Please provide detailed code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using following code!

```
Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    .Open
End With

Dim ObjRes
Set ObjRes = cn.Execute("Select * from [SourceData$]")
Do Until ObjRes.EOF
    cmbCompany.AddItem ObjRes.Fields.Item("Company").Value
    cmbProject.AddItem ObjRes.Fields.Item("Project").Value

    ObjRes.MoveNext
Loop

Set ObjRes = Nothing
```